# Cefsharp printpreview

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm trying to do a preview, since there is no standard procedure. How can this be done?

I'm trying to save it to PDF. But firstly, browser do not follow the set margins and secondly, I need to dynamically change the print margins. I'm trying to create a new component of the browser, but only a link in memory to the existing one is transferred to the new instance.

I will be grateful for the help!

Comment: corrected punctuation

Answer (score 0):

I send you this code for vb .net
I open into new form a page with cefsharp 
and i save pdf with the margin 
after print this pdf

```
browser.PrintToPdfAsync(RisultatiPath & "Temp\out.pdf", New PdfPrintSettings With {
               .BackgroundsEnabled = True,
               .HeaderFooterEnabled = False,
               .Landscape = False,
               .MarginType = CefPdfPrintMarginType.Custom,
               .MarginBottom = 0,
               .MarginTop = 0,
               .MarginLeft = 0.2,
               .MarginRight = 0,
               .PageWidth = 210000,
               .PageHeight = 297000
               })


    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Dim PrintPDF As New ProcessStartInfo
    PrintPDF.UseShellExecute = True
    PrintPDF.Verb = "print"
    PrintPDF.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    PrintPDF.FileName = RisultatiPath & "Temp\out.pdf"
    Process.Start(PrintPDF)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Me.Close()
```